# Sorting items into an array by property

Tags: python, arrays, regex, sorting, grouping

Consider a list containing a number of items, each containing information about the same `N` properties. Each of these properties can take on a certain limited (but perhaps unknown) number of discrete values. The list is not necessarily ordered.

I would like to sort these items into an `N`-dimensional array such that each property varies only along its own axis, i.e. is constant within any slice along that axis.

**Simplified Example:**

```
# Three properties
prop_1 = ['01','02','03','07']
prop_2 = ['foo','bar','baz']
prop_3 = ['yellow','red']

from itertools import product

# Consider this as the input
string_list = ['_'.join(s) for s in product(prop_1, prop_2, prop_3)]

# HOWEVER...

from random import shuffle

# Inputs may be unsorted
shuffle(string_list)
```

I now want to organize `string_list` into an array of shape `(4,3,2)` such that the first property varies along the first axis, & so on. That is, the expected output would be:

```
array([[['01_foo_yellow','01_foo_red'],
        ['01_bar_yellow','01_bar_red'],
        ['01_baz_yellow','01_baz_red']],

       [['02_foo_yellow','02_foo_red'],
        ['02_bar_yellow','02_bar_red'],
        ['02_baz_yellow','02_baz_red']],

       [['03_foo_yellow','03_foo_red'],
        ['03_bar_yellow','03_bar_red'],
        ['03_baz_yellow','03_baz_red']],

       [['07_foo_yellow','07_foo_red'],
        ['07_bar_yellow','07_bar_red'],
        ['07_baz_yellow','07_baz_red']]])
```

Each property is then constant within any slice along its own axis, i.e.:

```
A[3,...] # All strings containing '07' as property 1
A[:,1,:] # All strings containing 'bar' as property 2
A[...,0] # All strings containing 'yellow' as property 3
```

The method should be robust even when there are missing items. For example, if we remove `'02_bar_yellow'` and `'03_baz_red'` from the inputs, the shape of the output array should remain unchanged, with `None` where these entries would otherwise have been sorted:

```
array([[['01_foo_yellow','01_foo_red'],
        ['01_bar_yellow','01_bar_red'],
        ['01_baz_yellow','01_baz_red']],

       [['02_foo_yellow','02_foo_red'],
        [ None,          '02_bar_red'],
        ['02_baz_yellow','02_baz_red']],

       [['03_foo_yellow','03_foo_red'],
        ['03_bar_yellow','03_bar_red'],
        ['03_baz_yellow', None.      ]],

       [['07_foo_yellow','07_foo_red'],
        ['07_bar_yellow','07_bar_red'],
        ['07_baz_yellow','07_baz_red']]])
```

**The Problem:**

While the above illustrates the general idea, I am actually trying to get this to work for a set of regex `match` objects whose 'properties' are its capturing groups.

```
import re

pattern = '(\d+)_(\w+)_(\w+)'
regex = re.compile(pattern)

# Consider this as the input
matches = [re.match(s) for s in string_list]
```

I then want to sort according to the values given by the `group()` method of each `match` object.

Although it does not quite approach a solution, I can get the items sorted by slice along an axis using `itertools.groupby()`:

```
# Sort by the first capturing group
groupings = itertools.groupby(matches, key=lambda m: m.groups()[0])

grouped_strings = [[m.string for m in g] for n,g in groupings]
```

So the contents of `grouped_strings[3]` are the same as the slice `A[3,...]` given in the first example. However, these entries are given as a flattened array.

It occurs to me that I should be able to use `itertools.groupby` iteratively to achieve the proper sorting, but I can't quite figure it out. At the same time, I wonder if there is a simpler or more 'pythonic' way to achieve this.

Comment: Have you considered using numpy. It's a simple call to `reshape()` if it's a numpy array.

Comment: That would make things very simple, provided the input list can easily be sorted properly beforehand (for strings that is simple, for other objects not necessarily so). Another issue is that the lengths of the axes may not be known beforehand. Also, though I didn't mention it in the original post, I'd like a method that is robust in the case where the input list may have missing items.

Comment: Let me know if I've understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know the length of the axes initially, you need to get them, e.g., by using `set` or `np.unique`, which will also sort the result and compute an inverse index for you.

You can then make a boolean mask indicating which items were found and which weren't. It is trivial to map mask indices to the sorted label arrays.

Let's say you have three matches of interest, as in the example:

```
# Findall is the lazy shortcut that assumes only one match
matches = np.array([regex.findall(s) for s in string_list])
p1, i1 = np.unique(matches[:, 0], return_inverse=True)
p2, i2 = np.unique(matches[:, 1], return_inverse=True)
p3, i3 = np.unique(matches[:, 2], return_inverse=True)
mask = np.zeros((p1.size, p2.size, p3.size), dtype=bool)
mask[i1, i2, i3] = True
```

`p*` are the labels for the axes of your array. Since `np.unique` is sort-based, these will be unique and sorted.

`i*` are the indices that map elements of `string_list` to each axis. This means that the fancy index `i1, i2, i3` indicates the locations in the boolean matrix corresponding to a match that was found.

This can be easily generalized with a loop over an arbitrary number of capturing groups.

```
# note the transpose
matches = np.array([regex.findall(s) for s in string_list]).T
# must be list because ragged
axes = [np.unique(x, return_inverse=True) for x in matches]
mask = np.zeros(tuple(x[0].size for x in axes), dtype=bool)
mask[tuple(x[1] for x in axes)] = True
```

Comment: This is very clever. It's not quite what I wanted but it shows how to get there. I only had to make a few slight adjustments: `mask = np.full(tuple(x[0].size for x in axes), None, dtype=np.object); mask[tuple(x[1] for x in axes)] = matches`.

Comment: Great solution! +1 from me :)!

Answer (score 1):

You could try with `np.reshape` with the intial string:

```
import numpy as np
output=np.array(string_list).reshape(4,3,2) 

print(output)
```

Output:

```
[[['01_foo_yellow' '01_foo_red']
  ['01_bar_yellow' '01_bar_red']
  ['01_baz_yellow' '01_baz_red']]

 [['02_foo_yellow' '02_foo_red']
  ['02_bar_yellow' '02_bar_red']
  ['02_baz_yellow' '02_baz_red']]

 [['03_foo_yellow' '03_foo_red']
  ['03_bar_yellow' '03_bar_red']
  ['03_baz_yellow' '03_baz_red']]

 [['07_foo_yellow' '07_foo_red']
  ['07_bar_yellow' '07_bar_red']
  ['07_baz_yellow' '07_baz_red']]]
```

Comment: I realized a need to clarify a few things which I have added to the question body: 1) the inputs may be unsorted (which could be trivial); 2) the lengths of the axes may not be known beforehand; and 3) there could be missing items in the input, in which case the output array should have `None` where those items would otherwise have been sorted.

Comment: Sorry @corvus , I just see your comment and the edit :(, but MadPhysicist's answer is the one!

Comment: No worries, I realized the question wasn't phrased as well as it could have been but I was having a hard time explaining myself. Thanks for your input!